# Underscored lines representing text to guess, then replacing the underscores by input text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a text, for example "This is a question" which has to be guessed via some clues.
At the app a user will see "_ _ _ _  _ _  _  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ *" in a EditText, what I need is that when the user inputs something in that EditText each "*" is replaced automatically and in order from left to right. So it will be like "T h i s  i s  a  q u _ _ _ _ _ _"

As i'm pretty new in this world i'm not sure if I have to add a Listener to the EditText which can replace user input with whatever is needed or something else.

Any response will be very appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: you need to implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) in your activity and override its methods to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this method whenever a key is typed:

```
 public static int getIndex(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("_", "").length();
}

public static String prepareOutput(String actual, String input) {
    input = input.replaceAll("_", "");
    int diff = actual.length() - input.length();
    if (diff < 0) {
        return input;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
        input += "_";
    }
    return input;
}
```

like this:

```
 final EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String input = s.toString();
            String output = prepareOutput("This is a question", input);
            if (output.compareTo(input) != 0) {
                ed.setText(output);
                ed.setSelection(getIndex(output));
            }
        }
    });
```